# Object reference error when getting data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My portal has worked fine for several years but nowadays I have problems with my some codes. I want to update my code but at the first step I have problems with login page. when I use FirstOrDefault I got error on object reference while the list is filled and contains 1 user.

```
int g = db.sp_GetUserData_ByUserName(model.UserName.Trim()).Count();
//it shows 1 
OSUserData userData1 = db.sp_GetUserData_ByUserName(model.UserName.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();
```

I didn't change this code and It works perfectly on the portal. However, I can't run it on my development server.

I checked again and I found that OSUserData constructor throws exception : Enumeration yielded no result. this is my class code :

```
  public OSUserData()
        {
            this.OSUploadedFilesMultipleUsers = new HashSet<OSUploadedFilesMultipleUser>();
            this.OSSalaryLists = new HashSet<OSSalaryList>();
            this.OSUploadedFiles = new HashSet<OSUploadedFile>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
        public string BranchParentNationalCode { get; set; }
        public string CitName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CouName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string FaxNo { get; set; }
        public string FollowCode { get; set; }
        public string Hozeh { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsBranch { get; set; }
        public string LoginStatus { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
        public string NewEconomicNo { get; set; }
        public string Oldeconomicno { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string ProIdTTMS { get; set; }
        public string ProName { get; set; }
        public string Provision { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string TaxOfficeCode { get; set; }
        public string TaxPayerType { get; set; }
        public string TelCode { get; set; }
        public string TelNo { get; set; }
        public string TprId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool Validate { get; set; }
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }
        public string OwnerShipTypeDesc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> OwnerShipTypeCode { get; set; }
        public bool Processed { get; set; }
        public bool CheckedUser { get; set; }
        public bool Blocked { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OSUploadedFilesMultipleUser> OSUploadedFilesMultipleUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OSSalaryList> OSSalaryLists { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OSUploadedFile> OSUploadedFiles { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why are you adding one single model inside a not initialized list? Make your variable `OSUserData userData1` or `var userData1`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add to a null/unreferenced/not initialized object/list. Initialize first the list

```
List<OSUserData> userData1 = new List<OSUserData>();
```

Then add it

```
var user = db.sp_GetUserData_ByUserName(model.UserName.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();

userData1.Add(new OSUserData{
   Prop1 = user.Prop1,
   Prop2 = user.Prop2,
   ......
});
```

Or if you only want one user, just make it var

```
var user = db.sp_GetUserData_ByUserName(model.UserName.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: what does the stored procedure returns? Is it the same property as OSUserData, is it mapped to the properties of the OSUserData?

Comment: Stored procedure has no problem. OSUserData constructor is the problem. It returns an erorr enumeration yielded no result.

Comment: you may also add the OSUserData class